# Problem in plotting results of NDsolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

This is an ODE, I want to plot `P` on x-axis and `vars` on y-axis. My code works fine but gives an empty plot

```
Subscript[V, 0] = -2.5;
Subscript[k, 0] = Pi/2;
\[Epsilon] = 0.05;
n = 10;
B = Sqrt[3];
Subscript[t, fin] = 25;

A = Table[Subscript[V, i], {i, n}];
For[j = 1, j < n + 1, j++, A[[j]] = 0];
A[[n/2]] = Subscript[V, 0]*(1 + \[Epsilon]); 
A[[n/2 + 1]] = Subscript[V, 0]*(1 - \[Epsilon]);
P = Table[Subscript[\[Alpha], i], {i, n}];
For[j = 1, j < n + 1, j++, P[[j]] = 0];
P[[n/2]] = 1; P[[n/2 + 1]] = 1;
Subscript[\[Phi], 0][t_] := Subscript[\[Phi], 1][t];
Subscript[\[Phi], n + 1][t_] := Subscript[\[Phi], n][t];

eqns = Table[{Sqrt[-1]*Subscript[\[Phi], i]'[t] == 
 A[[i]]*Subscript[\[Phi], i][t] - Subscript[\[Phi], i + 1][t] - 
  Subscript[\[Phi], i - 1][
   t] + (P[[i]]*Abs[Subscript[\[Phi], i][t]]^2*
    Subscript[\[Phi], i][t]), Subscript[\[Phi], i][0] == B}, {i, 
n}];
vars = Table[
Sum[Abs[\[Phi][i, Subscript[t, fin]]]^2, {i, n/2 + 2, n}], {i, 
25}]/Table[Sum[Abs[\[Phi][i, 0]]^2, {i, n/2 - 1}], {i, 25}];

sol = NDSolve[eqns, vars, {t, 0, 25}, 
Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "StiffnessTest" -> False}, 
MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8];
Plot=ListPlot[Table[vars /. First[%], {t, 0, 250}], 
PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400]
```

with `vars` explicitly given by `vars`$=\frac{\sum_{n>\frac{M}{2}+1}|\phi_n(t_{fin})|^2}{\sum_{n<\frac{M}{2}}|\phi_n(0)|^2}$

Comment: Check `vars` beceause is nonsense ?

Comment: No, its the transmission coefficient. So essentially it will be a plot of transmission coefficient as a function of `P`. did I make a mistake in writing it appropriately you mean?

Comment: Replace by my code: `vars = Table[Subscript[\[Phi], i][t], {i, 0, n}];Plot[Evaluate[vars /. sol // ReIm], {t, 0, 25}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ImageSize -> 400, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[\[Phi][i][t], {i, 0, n}]]`?

Comment: `vars`=$\frac{\sum_{n>\frac{M}{2}+1}|\phi_n(t_{fin})|^2}{\sum_{n<\frac{M}{2}}|\phi_n(0)|^2}$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, there's an output from your code, but not the required one. Actually this should be a plot for `vars` which I wrote above, I tried to input this `vars` into Mathematica in my code above, but the try fails I guess because I get no output.

Comment: Delete yours: `vars = Table[
Sum[Abs[\[Phi][i, Subscript[t, fin]]]^2, {i, n/2 + 2, n}], {i, 
25}]/Table[Sum[Abs[\[Phi][i, 0]]^2, {i, n/2 - 1}], {i, 25}];Plot=ListPlot[Table[vars /. First[%], {t, 0, 250}], 
PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400]` and replace by mine code.For me works fine on MMA `11.3`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, OK I replaced the code with your `vars` and your `Plot` but I get an empty plot? I am also using MMA 11.3.

Comment: If I check your equation a see a lot of subscripted functions like `Subscript[\[Phi], 6][t]` were as  your variables look like `(Abs[\[Phi][7, 25]]^2) +...`. Your main problem is due to the use of subscripted variables!

Comment: Clear the kernel ``ClearAll["Global`*"]; Remove["Global`*"];`` and start again.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I have actually shut MMA down and started again, I tried again but I get empty output. Can you show the output you get?

Comment: See here : https://www.imgload.org/image/GPCVb

Comment: Is this a plot w.r.t `vars`=$\frac{\sum_{n>\frac{M}{2}+1}|\phi_n(t_{fin})|^2}{\sum_{n<\frac{M}{2}}|\phi_n(0)|^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that this code will be useful

```
Subscript[V, 0] = -2.5;
Subscript[k, 0] = Pi/2;
\[Epsilon] = 0.05;
n = 10;
B = Sqrt[3];
(*Subscript[t,fin]=25;*)

A = Table[Subscript[V, i], {i, n}];
For[j = 1, j < n + 1, j++, A[[j]] = 0];
A[[n/2]] = Subscript[V, 0]*(1 + \[Epsilon]);
A[[n/2 + 1]] = Subscript[V, 0]*(1 - \[Epsilon]);
P = Table[Subscript[\[Alpha], i], {i, n}];
For[j = 1, j < n + 1, j++, P[[j]] = 0];
P[[n/2]] = 1; P[[n/2 + 1]] = 1;
Subscript[\[Phi], 0][t_] := Subscript[\[Phi], 1][t];
Subscript[\[Phi], n + 1][t_] := Subscript[\[Phi], n][t];

eqns = Table[{Sqrt[-1]*Subscript[\[Phi], i]'[t] == 
     A[[i]]*Subscript[\[Phi], i][t] - Subscript[\[Phi], i + 1][t] - 
      Subscript[\[Phi], i - 1][
       t] + (P[[i]]*Abs[Subscript[\[Phi], i][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i][t]), Subscript[\[Phi], i][0] == B}, {i, 
    n}];


sol = NDSolve[eqns, 
   Table[Subscript[\[Phi], i][t], {i, 1, n}], {t, 0, 25}, 
   Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "StiffnessTest" -> False}, 
   MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8];
f[i_, t_] := Abs[Subscript[\[Phi], i][t]]^2 /. sol
A = Sum[f[i, t] /. t -> 0, {i, 1, n/2 - 1}];
Plot[Sum[f[i, t], {i, n/2 + 2, n}]/A, {t, 0, 25}, 
 PlotLabel -> "vars(t)"]

Table[Plot[
  Evaluate[Abs[Subscript[\[Phi], i][t]]^2 /. sol], {t, 0, 25}, 
  PlotLabel -> i, AxesLabel -> Automatic], {i, 1, n}]
```

[image: fig1]

If there is a dependence on the parameter, then use the following code

```
Subscript[V, 0] = -2.5;
Subscript[k, 0] = Pi/2;
\[Epsilon] = 0.05;
n = 10;
B = Sqrt[3];
Subscript[t, fin] = 25;

A = Table[Subscript[V, i], {i, n}];
For[j = 1, j < n + 1, j++, A[[j]] = 0];
A[[n/2]] = Subscript[V, 0]*(1 + \[Epsilon]);
A[[n/2 + 1]] = Subscript[V, 0]*(1 - \[Epsilon]);
P = Table[Subscript[\[Alpha], i], {i, n}];
For[j = 1, j < n + 1, j++, P[[j]] = 0];
P[[n/2]] = p0; P[[n/2 + 1]] = p0;
Subscript[\[Phi], 0][t_] := Subscript[\[Phi], 1][t];
Subscript[\[Phi], n + 1][t_] := Subscript[\[Phi], n][t];

eqns = Table[{Sqrt[-1]*Subscript[\[Phi], i]'[t] == 
     A[[i]]*Subscript[\[Phi], i][t] - Subscript[\[Phi], i + 1][t] - 
      Subscript[\[Phi], i - 1][
       t] + (P[[i]]*Abs[Subscript[\[Phi], i][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i][t]), Subscript[\[Phi], i][0] == B}, {i, 
    n}];


F = Table[
   ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns, 
    Subscript[\[Phi], i], {t, 0, 25}, {p0}], {i, 1, n}];



{Plot3D[Evaluate[Abs[F[[n/2]][p0][t]]^2], {p0, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 25}, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotLabel -> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(5\)]\)(p0,t)", 
  AxesLabel -> {"p0", "t", ""}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[
   Sum[Abs[F[[i]][p0][t]]^2, {i, n/2 + 2, n}]/
    Sum[Abs[F[[i]][p0][0]]^2, {i, 1, n/2 - 1}]], {p0, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 
   25}, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLabel -> "vars(p0,t)",
   AxesLabel -> {"p0", "t", ""}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is very helpful. Is it possible to plot `vars` as function of `P`, instead of `vars(t)`?

Comment: This is possible, but by definition P = 0. There must be parameters or at least one parameter, eg `For[j = 1, j < n + 1, j++, P[[j]] = p0];`

Comment: But `P`$\neq 0$ for $\frac{M}{2}$ and $\frac{M}{2}+1$, is it still not possible? Like if one defines a parameter for this part, as you mentioned above.

Comment: Ok,  `P= {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}`.  Where is the parameter?

Comment: Oh I got it, Yes this part `P[[n/2]] = 1; P[[n/2 + 1]] = 1;` should be given a  parameter instead of 1.

Comment: Will it be possible if, say `P[[n/2]] = p0; P[[n/2 + 1]] = p0` and one can set the range for `p0` to be from `0` to `10`?

Comment: `Plot3D[vars[p0,t],{p0,10},{t,0,25}]` ?

Comment: I updated the solution, added 3D figure. It's probably what you wanted to see.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes exactly, now I understand my mistakes.

Comment: One more thing if you could help: If we want a 2D plot with  `vars` on y-axis for $t=25$ fixed, then can we plot a 2D output with `vars(t=25)` on y-axis and `p0` on x-axis?

Comment: I tried the following, but with error `Plot[(\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(2\)] + 2\), \(n\)]\(f[i, t]\)\) /. 
  t -> 25)/A, {p0, 0, 10}]`